# Authentication issue with IIS

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-6

using IIS 6

I have the default web site that works and can authenticate users to the domain when they connect.

I have created a second website, siteb, put a host (a) record into DNS, I can browse to it as long as I have use anonymous access, when I select windows authentication, it fails...

not sure what i'm missing here...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This goes beyond just IIS if you're using Integrated Windows Authentication.  You've created "siteb" in DNS which allows your users to connect to it so this is good.  However, when their browser requests a Kerberos ticket for "siteb" from Active Directory, AD is probably responding that it cannot find "siteb".  You can verify this with Wireshark.

The fix is to add "siteb" (and any other permutations with which you expect users to access the site) as an additional servicePrincipalName for the server's machine account in AD.  You can accomplish this with the "setspn.exe" utility.  It should be available on your domain controller.  If not, you can install it from the [Windows 2003 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326).

Some examples of adding a UPN alias with setspn on the DC are:

```
setspn.exe –A HTTP/siteb <server hostname> 
setspn.exe –A HTTP/siteb.acme.com <server hostname>
```

This should take effect immediately.  The final step is ensuring that the browser "trusts" the new website name.  In Internet Explorer, for IWA to occur automatically, the server name should be listed in either the Trusted Sites or Intranet zone.

Of course, you could avoid all this hoopla by having the 2nd website just run on a different port under the same name, e.g.: `http://sitea:81`